# Assigning Accessors in after_initiialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have a model (to_js is a custom method, from [here](http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/58-ruby-time-to-javascript), to transform a ruby Time into JS Date format):

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :js_start_time

  def after_initialize
    js_start_time = self.start_time.to_js
  end
end
```

When I find an instance of that model in the console, js_start_time is nil.  Why is this?  Thank you.

EDIT: Stupid mistake.  Needed to do:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :js_start_time
  after_find :set_js_time

  def set_js_time
    self.js_start_time = self.start_time.to_js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have to do a little exploring with what your data is doing.

If you havn't already, add the gem : `ruby-debug`

Then throw the line `debugger` before your `nil` call like so :

```
def after_initialize
  debugger # <---- add this here.
  js_start_time = self.start_time.to_js
end
```

Then run your server `rails s --debugger`

When you get to the debugger, try and figure out what instant variables and attributes are available.

Also, show us what the the stack trace error is saying!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm an idiot.  Classic stupid mistake -- I needed to do after_initialize :set_length, then write that method, and also place 'self.' before js_start_time.  But thanks -- I now know how to use ruby-debug.